# AspNetZero and Redis - why are there so many Redis Gets for the same data within microseconds of each other?

Tags: .net-core, redis, aspnetzero

I have recently started to see many RedisTimeoutExceptions being thrown within our application.  I'm trying to understand *what* AspNetZero (and ABP) are doing.  I ran a MONITOR to see what the traffic looks like and can't understand it.

Why so many 'gets'?

I realize that every API method call requires a GET to ensure that the user has authorization and that this generates a lot of activity, but why get the same data over and over and over again?

[image: redis monitor]